# My page showing up with a title, but with the content div empty, but only for users

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I've created a new content type that has the default 4 fields (Title, Body, Meta tags, URL path settings) and one List(integer) that I added.  I called it "Basic page".

When I create a new Basic page node and put in some data, it will work as long as I'm logged in as admin.  If I log in as any other user, the page title will show up, but the body will be blank.

The content div for a user is actually completely empty.  The admin has content for it, but any other user does not.

```
<h1 class="page-title">New Test Page</h1>
<div class="region region-content">
  <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
    <div class="content">
      <div id="node-2291627" class="node node-page clearfix">
        <div class="content"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've looked through the user permissions for this node type, and that doesn't seem to be affecting anything (though I could have easily missed something).  The display isn't set to . I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really sounds like a permissions problem. Do you (or did you) have [field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) installed?

If you do you will have to set field level permissions (which are separate) from node permissions. If you have field permissions viewing/editing a node does not mean a user can view/edit specific fields, you will have to specify these permissions in addition to the overall node permissions.

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly what the problem was.  The body field was set to private.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: sweet good to hear!